# Showing $|\mathcal{I}_X|=\sum_{r=0}^n{n \choose r}^2r!$.

Tags: combinatorics, semigroups, inverse-semigroups

This is Exercise 5.11.3 of Howie's *"Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory"*.

> **Definition 1:** Let $X$ be a set. The *symmetric inverse semigroup*, denoted $\mathcal{I}_X$, consists of all partial one-to-one maps of X under composition of relations.

### The Question:

> If $\lvert X\rvert=n$, show that $$\lvert\mathcal{I}_X\rvert=\sum_{r=0}^n{n \choose r}^2r!.$$

### My Attempt:

Let $\alpha$ be a one-to-one partial map on $X$. Let $\lvert \operatorname{im}(\alpha)\rvert=k$. Then there are ${n \choose k}$ possible choices for the elements of $\operatorname{im}(\alpha)$, up to the $k!$ possible permutations of these elements. Summing over $k$ then gives $\lvert\mathcal{I}_X\rvert$, but this is wrong.

I don't understand where the extra factor of ${n\choose k}$ comes from.

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial means that your domain is not all $X,$ hence you also have to choose the $r$ elements of the domain, hence $\binom{n}{r}.$

Comment: I understand that, but why isn't one ${n\choose r}$ enough?

Comment: Oh, elements of the *domain* - sorry! - yes, I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: Because you need to choose the domain and the image. Two of them. They can be different and you have still bijections.

Comment: So ${n\choose r}$ to get the domain, another ${n\choose r}$ to get the image, and then $r!$ to permute the image elements.

Comment: @Shaun Yes sir.